# How to apply multiple filters using Redux Toolkit

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to filter out data by category e.g. type, brand, color, gender using Redux Toolkit.
The filters work individually but filters don't work together. If I filter out the brand and then the color, the brand filter is not working.
What do I have to do to make this work?

```
const initialState = {
    products: data,
    filteredItems: data,
}

export const filterSlice = createSlice({
    name: "filter",
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        filterCategory: (state, action) => {
            if (action.payload === "All") {
                return initialState
            } else
            state.filteredItems = state.products.filter(
                (item) => item.category === action.payload
            ) 
        },
        filterGender: (state, action) => {
            state.filteredItems = state.products.filter(
                (item) => item.gender === action.payload
            ) 
        },
        filterColor: (state, action) => {
            state.filteredItems = state.products.filter(
                (item) => item.color === action.payload
            )
        },
        filterBrand: (state, action) => {
            state.filteredItems= state.products.filter(
                (item) => item.brand === action.payload
            )
        },
    }
})
```

I have tried writing the filters in one reducer but it still doesn't work

Comment: Each filter does its own thing. I would just enable/disable each filter in the slice and when you render the data, filter and resolve all active filters in the render phase using `Array.prototype.every`. There is no need to store a copy of the filtered data in Redux.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably do something like

```
const initialState = {
    products: data,
    filteredItems: data,
    filters: {}
}

reducers: {
    filterCategory: (state, action) => {
        if (action.payload === "All") {
            return initialState
        } else {
            state.filters = { ...state.filters, category: action.payload }
            state.filteredItems = state.products;
        ) 
    },
    // ...etc.
    Object.entries(state.filters).forEach(([key, value]) => {
        state.filteredItems = state.filteredItems.filter(
            (item) => item[key] === value
        );
    });
    return state;
}
```

So that you save which filters are active, then set filteredItems to the full list of items, and then apply each filter individually.